# Calculate size of 1 minute PCM recording

Tags: java, audio

I want to calculate how much 1 minute of recording does take. I know sampleRate, nr of channels and bit depth.

From as I know, the sample rate is how many samples are given into a second. Bit depth is how many bits are in 1 sample.

So,

- sampleRate = 44100
- bitDepth = 16 (2 bytes per sample)
- channels = 2
- time = 60 sec

**My formula is:** `(44100 * (16 / 8)) * 60` = ~5 MB per minute.

But I'm missing nr of channels, I don't know how to integrate it in my formula. All I know about nr of channels is that when stereo recording, each frame is composed from 2 samples and when mono recording each frame is composed by 1 sample.

Please show me the correct formula to compute the size of 1 minute recording.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.


Comment: just take what you have and multiply by the channel count

Comment: @SamDufel - please respond with an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to multiply by the number of channels

Size per minute (in bytes):

```
sampleRate * (bitDepth / 8) * channelCount * 60
```

Comment: Why 8?
What does **8** mean for wav format?

Comment: 8, because you're calculating a number of Bytes, and there are 8 Bits in a Byte.